# Mergear un array y ponerlo al inicio laravel - livewire

Tags: php, laravel, array, livewire

tengo un array inicial en el que luego de un evento en livewire hago un merge de esta manera

```
$this->notifications[] = $event;
```

y lo inserta, pero lo inserta al final, quiero enviar $event al inicio del array sin cambiar el orden del resto del array, cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: crea un array temporal y agrega primero event, luego le agregas notifications , luego iguala notifications a el array temporal, o intenta con UNSHIFT de php https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: @HeynerMartinez gracias! era justo lo que necesitaba